# Function in PHP to set cookie, for my login script

Tags: php, html, session

I followed [this guide](http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/php_login_code.htm) as an attempt to write a login script for my hobby webpage.

Problem is when I want to incorporate it into my page, problems occur.

I'm trying to make an admin panel.

In the top of the frame I want the login form to be

[image: page example]

When I log in, I'd like the `Login form area` to change into `Logout fields`.

My problem is that all cookie-related calls has to be done before the HTML code starts...

So:

- When you log in: content of the page should be displayed ( a simple include ).
- When you log in: login area changes into logout area, thus hiding the login fields and        displaying name of user logged in...
- and when logging out: content and logout should disappear and show login fields again.

How can this be done (give examples like pseudo code)?

PS. Im not a PHP nerd, still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your login Data into your current session.

```
$_SESSION["username"] = $user;
```

But don't forget to call session_start() at the top of your code.

After that you check whether "$_SESSION["username"]" is set with your data. If so, you can change your content to whatever you like.

Example:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && loginSuccessful()) {
    include("AdminMenue.php");
}
```

loginSuccessful() should be a method that checks whether your Login Data can be found in your database.

More information about sessions can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: I have got it to work. I just need a simple solution for refreshing the page after loggin in, and logging out.

I enter login data, get logged in, but i have to press F5 to see the change... Same goes for logout.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  if ($_SESSION['username'])
    include "logout-fields.php";
  else
    include "login-form-area.php";
?>
```

something like this